# Cannot access the print document when I click it for second time

Tags: c#, listview, printing

I have a problem with printing, it says Cannot Access Disposed Object 'Print Preview Dialog'

I have created listviews.. If you want to print it, you must click the information in listview1 and find the ID that you clicked the item in listview1 on listview 3. Then you click the print. Okay that's good it seems so good but. When you choose second info and try to print it; Cannot Access Disposed Object 'Print Preview Dialog'. There's the code

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {


        StringFormat sformat = new StringFormat();
        sformat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;


        e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox1.Text + " "+ textBox2.Text +" "+ "Çalışanının Maaş Çıktısı",baslik,sb,240,50);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", gövde, sb, 75, 200);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Çalıştığı günler", baslik, sb, 150, 150);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Çalışma Süresi", baslik, sb, 540, 150);
        for (int i = 0; i < listView3.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(listView3.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text, gövde, sb, 150, 250 + (i * 30));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(listView3.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text, gövde, sb, 580, 250 + (i * 30));

        }
        e.Graphics.DrawString("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", gövde, sb, 75, 250 +(listView3.Items.Count * 30));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Ödenecek Miktar" + ":  " + listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[5].Text + " TL ", baslik, sb, 490, 250 + (listView3.Items.Count * 30)+30);
```

Here's the print button code:

```
 private void button16_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView3.Items.Count == 0 )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Önce kişinin çalışma geçmişini görüntüleyin!");
        }
        else
        {
            ppDialog.Show();
        }

    }
```

I'm about to get crazy please help me.